# Upload single executable release file on GitHub

Tags: python, github, pyinstaller, executable, release

I converted my Python-Program *program.py* to a single executable file *program_v1.0* on my Mac using pyinstaller. However, when I upload the file to my Github Releases, the file program_v1.0.app.zip appears. Is there a way I can upload a single, "precompiled" program for each operating system, such that the end user just downloads a single file he can easily use? (program.py is the source code of a GUI)

Comment: You may need to create separate executables for each OS.

Comment: Pyinstaller does not create OS-agnostic executables (see https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html) You would need to compile the program into an executable on Windows, Mac, Linux etc.. individually and they would be separate files for an end user to download for their OS. As for the *.zip file, try using the `--onefile` flag